# Issue: scraping on multiple pages has stopped working

Tags: r, rvest

I am scraping all the reviews of a hotel from Tripadvisor and my code is resulting in the following error: Error in data.frame(textoComentario, fechaComentario) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 5

I had used the following code to **scrape** another hotel and it worked, but I am failing to identify where the error is. I have tried using different CSS selectors, but nothing works. I was able to run the code fully one time but then the same reviews repeated itself over and over again. I don't know how to fix the issue.
I attach my code for easier understanding of the problem

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
#Link
web <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187499-d239247-Reviews-Melia_Girona-Girona_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html")
# Dataset to download the review sections
# 1. Texto comentarios
textoComentario<-web%>%
  html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC span")%>%
  html_text()
textoComentario

# 2. Fecha comentario
fechaComentario<-web%>%
  html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa")%>%
  html_text()
fechaComentario <- strsplit(fechaComentario, ": ")
fechaComentario <- unlist(lapply(fechaComentario, FUN = function(x) {x[2]}))
fechaComentario


datos<-data.frame(textoComentario,fechaComentario)

# To go through all the review pages
for(i in 1:174){
  # 1. url
  
  url<-paste0("https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187499-d239247-Reviews-or",i*10,"-Melia_Girona-Girona_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.htm")
  
  
  pagina<-read_html(url)
  
 
  textoComentario<-pagina%>%
    html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC span")%>%
    html_text()
  textoComentario

  fechaComentario<-pagina%>%
    html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa")%>%
    html_text()
  fechaComentario <- strsplit(fechaComentario, ": ")
  fechaComentario <- unlist(lapply(fechaComentario, FUN = function(x) {x[2]}))
  fechaComentario


  
  nuevosDatos<-data.frame(textoComentario,fechaComentario)
  
 
  datos<-rbind(datos,nuevosDatos)
  
  print(paste0("PÃƒÂ¡gina ",i))
}

df<- datos
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the issue is that at least one of the iterations in your loop is returning 6 elements in `textoComentario` instead of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textoComentario` and `fechaComentario` differ in length and thus cannot be combined in a data.frame the way you do it. The following code solves this by adding `NAs` to the shorter variable before combining the variables to a dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

Link
web <- read_html("https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187499-d239247-Reviews-Melia_Girona-Girona_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html")
# Dataset to download the review sections
# 1. Texto comentarios
textoComentario<-web%>%
  html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC span")%>%
  html_text()
textoComentario

# 2. Fecha comentario
fechaComentario<-web%>%
  html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa")%>%
  html_text()
fechaComentario <- strsplit(fechaComentario, ": ")
fechaComentario <- unlist(lapply(fechaComentario, FUN = function(x) {x[2]}))
fechaComentario


datos<-data.frame(textoComentario,fechaComentario)

# To go through all the review pages
for(i in 1:174){
  # 1. url

  url<-paste0("https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187499-d239247-Reviews-or",i*10,"-Melia_Girona-Girona_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.htm")
  print(i)

  pagina<-read_html(url)


  textoComentario<-pagina%>%
    html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC span")%>%
    html_text()


  fechaComentario<-pagina%>%
    html_nodes(".location-review-review-list-parts-EventDate__event_date--1epHa")%>%
    html_text()
  fechaComentario <- strsplit(fechaComentario, ": ")
  fechaComentario <- unlist(lapply(fechaComentario, FUN = function(x) {x[2]}))
  fechaComentario

  #make sure variables have equal length, if not add NAs to shorter variable
  if (length(textoComentario) < length(fechaComentario)) {textoComentario[length(textoComentario):length(fechaComentario)] <- NA}
  if (length(fechaComentario) < length(textoComentario)) {fechaComentario[length(fechaComentario):length(textoComentario)] <- NA}

  nuevosDatos<-data.frame(textoComentario,fechaComentario)

  datos<-rbind(datos,nuevosDatos)

  print(paste0("PÃƒÂ¡gina ",i))
}
```

This results in a total of 21 `NA` values in `fechaComentario`:

```
df %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  filter(is.na(textoComentario) | is.na(fechaComentario))

# A tibble: 21 x 2
   textoComentario                                                                                                                                                      fechaComentario
   <fct>                                                                                                                                                                <fct>          
 1 "Empezaré por lo bueno. Solo el desayuno (buffet bastante completo) merece las cuatro estrellas, al margen del buen hacer del personal, muy atento, también en rece~ NA             
 2 "…"                                                                                                                                                                  NA             
 3 "Empezaré por lo bueno. Solo el desayuno (buffet bastante completo) merece las cuatro estrellas, al margen del buen hacer del personal, muy atento, también en rece~ NA             
 4 "…"                                                                                                                                                                  NA             
 5 "La estancia fue muy bien tanto en el trato en la recepción Como en en la cafetería . Creo que seria buena idea cambiar las bañeras por ducha , pues las bañeras so~ NA             
 6 "hotel necesita una reforma  Habitaciones e instalaciones antiguas  Desayuno bueno  Ubicación regular lejos del centro en un barrio nada bueno. Los botes de gel y ~ NA             
 7 "Es un hotel fantastico para realizar viajes de negocios y de placer. Desde la restauracion (camareros y camareras incluidas), pasando por recepcion y las habitaci~ NA             
 8 "El equipo Melià nos atendió en todo momento con la mejor de sus sonrisas, ayudándonos con todas las dudas que nos surgieron. El hotel tiene una situación muy buen~ NA             
 9 "Reserve una habitación doble estándar para una noche. Por la noche se escuchaba el ascensor, la habitación estaba pared con pared con él; no me di cuenta al dejar~ NA             
10 "…"                                                                                                                                                                  NA             
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Perfect! Could you mark the question as resolved (checkmark on the left)?